# Draw stacked charts in amcharts by ajax api json response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, amcharts

I'm using `amcharts` (stacked chart), i want to show the values in stacked chart which i get from `jquery ajax api` call (`json format`)
I've tried it but i'm able to achieve this,
Can anybody having clue on this.

Check this fiddle for my code:-

[Fiddle][1]
    [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/JonHome/t6okfjc0/

Comment: The url http://10.26.32.4/api/rating-service/rate/ridecount/week from your fiddle code won't be accessible outside your network.

Comment: @ketan-yekale
This is json response from api call
[
    {
        "creationDate": "23/08/18",
        "activeTrip": 2,
        "cancelledTrip": 3,
        "completedTrip": 0
    },
    {
        "creationDate": "22/08/18",
        "activeTrip": 0,
        "cancelledTrip": 1,
        "completedTrip": 0
    }
]

Just update the code what i missed, i'll put api link & try to achieve

Comment: Please add absolute url for /bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: @ketan-yekale fiddle is updated  
http://jsfiddle.net/JonHome/5tkswdcr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **chart.write()** method accepts **id** of an HTML element and you are passing the <del>class</del>

Change:

<del>chart.write("chartdiv");</del>

to:

**chart.write("rides");**

**Soruce Code:**

> The JS code below shows IIFE equivalent of your AJAX success. You can convert the IIFE (**function (chartData){...}**)([...]) to AJAX success method as **success: function (chartData){...}**

```js
        (function (chartData) {
            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                /* SERIAL CHART  */
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();

                /* chart.type = serial, */

                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.categoryField = "creationDate";
                chart.startDuration = 1;
                chart.plotAreaBorderColor = "#DADADA";
                chart.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 1; /*  this single line makes the chart a bar chart */
                chart.rotate = false;
                
                /*  AXES */
                /*  Category  Axis*/
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
                categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
                categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;

                /*  Value Axis */
                var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                valueAxis.stackType;
                valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
                valueAxis.position = "top";
                chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                /*  GRAPHS */
                /*  first graph  */
                var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph1.type = "column";
                graph1.title = "active Trips";
                graph1.valueField = "activeTrip";
                graph1.balloonText = "active Trips:[[value]]";
                graph1.lineAlpha = 0;
                graph1.fillColors = "#ADD981";
                graph1.fillAlphas = 1;
                chart.addGraph(graph1);

                /* second graph */
                var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph2.type = "column";
                graph2.title = "cancelled Trips";
                graph2.valueField = "cancelledTrip";
                graph2.balloonText = "cancelled Trips:[[value]]";
                graph2.lineAlpha = 0;
                graph2.fillColors = "#81acd9";
                graph2.fillAlphas = 1;
                chart.addGraph(graph2);

                /*  Third graph */
                var graph3 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph3.type = "column";
                graph3.title = "completed Trips";
                graph3.valueField = "completedTrip";
                graph3.balloonText = "completed Trips:[[value]]";
                graph3.lineAlpha = 0;
                graph3.fillColors = "#9972C1";
                graph3.fillAlphas = 1;
                chart.addGraph(graph3);

                /* LEGEND  */
                var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                chart.addLegend(legend);

                /*  WRITE */
                chart.write("rides");
            });
        })([{
            "creationDate": "23/08/18",
            "activeTrip": 2,
            "cancelledTrip": 3,
            "completedTrip": 3
        }, {
            "creationDate": "22/08/18",
            "activeTrip": 2,
            "cancelledTrip": 1,
            "completedTrip": 10
        }])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="rides" class="chartdiv" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5tkswdcr/5/

Comment: i already achive this by using dataloader plugin, but i want it by calling api(get method) through jquery ajax coz i have another api (post method)to draw graphs.